# `svn checkout` on the SVN server causes the repo to break with a 301 error

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, nginx, httpd

We have an nginx server which proxies to a standard set-up of Apache+SVN. The nginx set-up is a very simple proxy:

```
server {
    server_name svn.ourdomain.tld;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

Apache is set-up as follows:

```
<Location />
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/svn
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authentication Required"
    AuthUserFile /var/svn/.auth
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

...which allows us to access repositories using something like `http://svn.ourdomain.tld/repo`. We've been running this set-up now for about 2 years without issue.

Recently we've found that we need to check out one of the repositories onto the server itself, however whenever we do so it seems to break the repo. From that point on, it will only respond with a `301 Moved Permanently` error.

We've tried:

- `svn co file:///path/to/repo`
- `svn co svn://localhost/repo`
- `svn co svn://svn.ourdomain.tld/repo`
- `svn co svn+ssh://localhost/repo`
- `svn co svn+ssh://svn.ourdomain.tld/repo`
- `svn co http://localhost/repo`
- `svn co http://svn.ourdomain.tld/repo`

Also tried bypassing nginx, and get the same error:

- `svn co http://localhost:8080/repo`
- `svn co http://svn.ourdomain.tld:8080/repo`

Checking out from a different machine works as expected *until* we attempt to check out on the server, after that it refuses with the same `301` error.

What is more confusing is that this repository server also hosts our [Hudson](https://hudson.dev.java.net/)CI server, which can pulls and builds our projects hourly. This leads us to suspect that it's the svn client which is causing an error in communication.

Its also very confusing that removing then re-creating the repo using `svnadmin` doesn't reset the error - the repo is **still** unavailable even though it's "new"! Restarting apache and subversion (svnserve) has no effect on this, or the original error.

Version information:

- OS: 64-bit CentOS 4.2, 2.6.27 kernel
- svn client: 1.4.2 (same for both server and remote clients)
- svn server: 1.4.2
- httpd: 2.2.3

**UPDATE:**

This also happens with `svn export` when run on the repo server. Ran from any other box/client, there isn't a problem. Here's the workflow, to help clarify the error:

1. `[~repo-server~]# svnadmin create {repo}; chown -Rf www:www {repo}`
2. `[remote-client]# svn checkout http://svn.ourdomain.tld/repo`
3. `[remote-client]# svn add file; svn ci -m ''`
4. `[~repo-server~]# cd /var/www; svn export file:///path/to/repo/trunk ourproject`
5. `[remote-client]# svn update` *fails with 301 error*

I can also confirm that the hostname of the box doesn't have an effect here, which is very odd: whether or not `svn.ourdomain.tld` is added to `/etc/hosts` it still breaks - we thought it could be an issue with localhost routing, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Are we missing something in the documentation which states you can't checkout a repo when the server is on the same box? How can we stop the repos becoming corrupt when we checkout locally?

Answer (score 0):

svn doesn't handle HTTP redirects (that's what the 301 error is), look where the redirects points to (wget, wireshark), checkout from there.

Also it is apache specific problem, the virtual host configuration can be breaking it.

Comment: Doesn't explain why using the `file://` protocol would also cause it to break.

Comment: svn gives you 301 error on file:// ? That's *weird*

Comment: Interestingly, `curl` shows the 301 is returned when the trailing slash is left off. Adding it fixes curl, but it still breaks locally. Remote checkouts (from a different box) work either way.

Comment: @Hubert - its always *after* a checkout attempt on the repo server; whether it's successful or not, subsequent co's from local and remote boxes fail.

Comment: That would suggest that the rewriting is broken somewhere (forces "/" at the end perhaps)

Comment: Have you compared the permissions on files before and after the feral checkout?

Comment: @Hubert - there isn't any explicit rewriting going on. Nginx does a simple `proxy_pass`, and that's it (updated message above).

Comment: @Hubert - file permissions don't change, and are *exactly* the same as other, working repos.

Comment: Then sorry, it looks like I won't be able to help you. I have never used nginx. (you may want to add it to tags)

Comment: @Hubert - I don't think it's an nginx problem; I can bypass nginx by setting the port in the url, and still get the same problem.

Comment: So, you can do a "http://localhost:8080/repo" checkout only once? On second try it gives 301? If it breaks after using file:// while apache is running, that's known behavior and AFAICR in official documentation.